# Spring boot tomcat using +4000% CPU

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, netflix-zuul, hystrix

I using zuul as API edge for my microservice infrastructure, I have a strong CPU with 32 and 56 thread.
As I checked, gateway service using CPU more than %4000!
I used JMX to dump and trace CPU usage.
I see "`https-jsse-nio`" have 200 instances and every instance using a huge CPU resource.
Please see the traces:

[image][image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the SSL Handshake problem, It seems a bug from Tomcat.